# read data from my app's sqlite database using USB cable

Tags: android, sqlite, usb

I would like to read data from my app's sqlite database that is installed on a real device into a windows computer. I want to connect the two using a USB cable or any other method but not internet
1. Is this possible? Yes in debug mode, i can see the data in eclipse's LogCat but how do i access this data?
2. Can you point me to some literature that can help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in your main activity and restart your activity.  Make sure this code has been called onc and set proper sd card path.   Install the sqlite manager tool on windows and see your data.

```
        try
        {
        String inFileName = "//data/data/com.needzapp.debug/databases/your_db_name";
        File dbFile = new File(inFileName);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dbFile);
        String outFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/NeedzApp_DB";
        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = fis.read(buffer))>0){
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        //Close the streams
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        fis.close();
    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        Timber.e("File Not found ", e.toString());
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e)
    {
        Timber.e("NUll pointer" , e.toString());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("exception on exporting DB");
    }
```

Comment: ThanK you chain. The code above extracts the database from the device and places it on the SD card where i can access it. do you know if there is a way i can connect to the database from Access using VBA?